# How to pass values from Child Array to a Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My requirement is as follows

In parent component, i am passing an array of Child Components(array can be 1 or more than 1)
[image]

As the image shows, a child component consists of elements like, input[type=range], input[type=number], dropdown menu, etc

Parent component has a button

```
<button>Search Location</button>
```

When I click on Search button in Parent, I need the value of every single elements in each Child Component,
for eg. structure can be as follows

```
let finalObj={
    child1: {
        dropValue: "Room1",
        cond: "AND"
    },
   child2: {
        inputVal: 50,
        cond: "OR"
   },
   child[n]: {
        rangeVal: 1,
        cond: ""
   }
}
```

Also, we can change the value again(before clicking search), and Search button should always pickup, the current set value of each component.

I am not sure how to go ahead with this. Any pointers will be really helpful. Please help

Answer (score 0):

So you need to change an array of components into an object of...  well first of all that's a `.reduce` use.

```js
const almostFinalObj = components.reduce((retval, each, i) => {
   retval['child'+i] = each;
   return retval;
}, {});
```

That will give an object like

```js
almostFinalObj = {
   child1: component1,
   child2: component2,
   childN: componentN,
}
```

Now we can `.forEach` through it, transforming each child component into whatever format you're looking for. (I'm unclear on that part but maybe you can figure out the rest.)

```js
Object.keys(almostFinalObj).forEach((each, i, array) => {
  let component = array[i];
  array[i] = {};
  component.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(e => {
    array[i][e.name] = e.value;
  });
});
```

This assumes the `name` attribute exists on each element in each child row-component. (As in, each radio button in your example has `<input type='radio' name='cond' .... />`.) You could use `id` or even a `data-XXX` attribute as well instead of `e.name`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, 
I am able to create a almostFinalObj, which is of type as follows

var almostFinalObj={
0: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: "0", ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}
1: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: "1", ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}
}

Then for second step I am getting error as 
                 component.querySelectorAll is not a function ...

Object.keys returned ["child0", "child1"]

Comment: I am trying like below 
let elms=document.querySelectorAll('input[name="numbName"]')
elms.forEach(e=>{ console.log(e.value)  })

I am not sure if this is an elegant way to get value of each element from each component 

I dont want to use ref, and I have'nt found any other way yet....

Comment: you can `const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component)`